# Javascript code executing out of order, can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this piece of code to work and it seems to be running out of order. I noticed this in the console logs.

```js
<script>
            var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");
            var myHTML = '';
            var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('items/');
            databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot)
            {
              snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) 
              {
                var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                myHTML += '<div class="card">';
                myHTML += '<div class="card-body">';
                var urlimage = '';
                storageRef.child('images/'+ childData.id +'.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                    urlimage = url;
                    console.log(urlimage);
                });
                console.log('url outside of function is: '+urlimage);
                myHTML += '<img src="'+ urlimage +'" class="img-thumbnail" height="">';
                console.log('images/'+ childData.id +'.jpg');
                myHTML += '<h4>'+ childData.sku + ' - ' + childData.name +'</h4>';
                myHTML += '</div>';
                myHTML += '</div>';
              });
              wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML;
            });
          </script>
```

It seems that the code is running console.log('url outside of function is: '+urlimage); before it runs console.log(urlimage);

I am not too familiar with Javascript yet and I hope I can get some help with this one.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's because of async! Use another `.then()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
storageRef.child('images/'+ childData.id +'.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                urlimage = url;
                console.log(urlimage);
            });
```

The piece of code above from the code you provided actually uses Promises. You usually use promises when dealing with asynchronous data, for example, data from a server. While that piece of code is processing, other lines of code are being executed, thereby leading to what you are observing. The behavior of asynchronous code cannot be usually predicted.

To use `urlimage` you can do something like this.

```
storageRef.child('images/'+ childData.id +'.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
myHTML += '<img src="'+ url +'" class="img-thumbnail" height="">';
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried your solution but it seems that now it just skips the myHTML += '<img src="'+ url +'" class="img-thumbnail" height="">'; until the end. Is there any way I can wait for the promise to resolve before proceeding?

Comment: You can also include the other lines of codes too. Those beginning with `myHTML +=` inside the promise's function

Comment: Thanks. I've done that and not it seems to delay the entire myHTML string concatenation to a point where wrapper.innerHTML is storing an empty myHTML. Is there anything I can do to delay the execution of the rest of the javascript code? Thanks a bunch for your time and expertise.

Comment: You could delay the execution using setTimeout but that is definitely not the right way to go. I think the whole code needs restructuring but I cannot figure out how to do that yet especially with the fact that I'm not so familiar with firebase.

Answer (score 1):

`getDownloadURL().then(...)` looks like an asynchronous function to me. Asynchronous (async for short) means that the javascript makes an external request (e.g. download a file) and then executes a callback function (the argument to `then`) once the external request is complete. In general you should expect javascript async callbacks to execute after the entire function call stack that starts the request.

Most programming languages with asynchronous functions will have a facility to wait, which is often called "blocking", but Javascript is an exception.

The reason Javascript does not permit blocking is Javascript engines are single threaded, so blocking on an operation blocks the whole system.

So for a long time, couldn't block a function to wait for the async calls to finish and pick up as if they were ordinary synchronous calls.

This is so inconvenient, Javascript eventually introduced `async` functions and the `await` keyword, which does what you want.

```
async function buildHtml(snapshot) {
   // Note the novel for-loop syntax. The inner function in forEach would break async.
   for(childSnapshot of snapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      myHTML += '<div class="card">';
      myHTML += '<div class="card-body">';
      var urlimage = await storageRef.child('images/'+ childData.id +'.jpg').getDownloadURL(); // global state may change here
      myHTML += '<img src="'+ urlimage +'" class="img-thumbnail" height="">';
      myHTML += '<h4>'+ childData.sku + ' - ' + childData.name +'</h4>';
      myHTML += '</div>';
      myHTML += '</div>';
   }
   wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. That does seem to be the issue. Is there any way I can wait for the callback function to resolve before proceeding?

Comment: @JW yes, `await`. It's new, surprisingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have asynchronous code here. Looks like `getDownloadURL()` is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I don't know what that function do (google says it is from firebase), but it comes from external library. And it can take some time to execute.

Even if it takes few milliseconds. It is always moved at the end of event loop.

Comment: the wording always doesn't suit with async.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That does seem to be the issue. Is there any way I can wait for the callback function to resolve before proceeding?